# Synology DSM behind NGINX: How to proxy_pass url for a shared file?

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy, synology

I can access Synology DSM without problems behind my NGINX (it's NOT the Synology NGINX!) with following conf:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name dsm.mydomain.de;
    ssl_certificate
    /etc/nginx/ssl/live/dsm.mydomain.de/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/live/dsm.mydomain.de/privkey.pem;

     location / {
        return 301 https://dsm.mydomain.de/dsm;
    }

    location /dsm/ {
        client_max_body_size 0;
        proxy_pass http://192.168.0.92:5000/;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_buffering on;
        proxy_read_timeout 120;
        proxy_max_temp_file_size 0m;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
    }
```

When I share a file via Synology FileStation I get a link to share, looking like
`https://dsm.mydomain.de/sharing/a4fJsmUYK`

So I thought adding the location /sharing/ to the server block will do the job..
But when accessing a shared-url it shows "is loading..." forever.

[image]

(I can access the shared file with `http://192.168.0.92:5000/sharing/a4fJsmUYK`)

Does anybody know a solution?